# Changes to default.aspx not showing

Tags: asp.net, terminal-services

We access a Terminal Services application by going to https://[our domain]/ts/en-US/Default.aspx, and clicking the application icon on that page.

We need an extra link on that page, which would point to a PDF file on the server, giving the Users some basic info about Terminal Service etc.

Although I'm not an asp.net programmer, I've opened the Default.aspx file on the server, and tried to edit it. As a first test, I simply added an extra period at the end of the copyright notice.

However, my change does not show up when I go to that webpage again. I've tried clearing the IE cache, but that didn't help.

I'm plumb out of ideas. Can anyone suggest something that I should try?

MTIA.

Comment: try to refresh using ctrl+F5

Comment: You may not need to know asp.net for this, just knowing html would be enough

Comment: Ctl+F5 certainly looked like it reloaded everything, judging by the way imgs rendered etc, but the aspx page had not changed.

Comment: Subin, that's what I thought. To test that I could make a change at all, I just added a period (".") to some copyright text. But it just isn't working. This simple change is not reflected in the webpage presented.